# Different result in validation set and testing set

Tags: tensorflow, testing, keras, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

Please give me some advice about the situation as following. I am currently training a Tensorflow model which is multi-label classification. Here is  the code for fitting model:

'''

```
model.compile(optimizer=OPTIM,
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy']) 

model.fit_generator(generator=trainGen,
                                epochs=Number_of_epochs,
                                steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                                validation_data=testGen,
                                validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                                callbacks=callbacks_list,
                                verbose=1)
```

'''

As you can see, the test set is used for validation step. after few epochs, I have got the accuracy for each attribute in validation step around 80- 90%. However, when I load the weight of model again to run model.predict in test set, the results generated is really low (just around 50%). It is not the same when using the test set in validation. I have checked all the steps of processing data and it is correct. Not sure why the results in predict and results at validation are different. Can anyone give me a hint about it?

Comment: Please show code for your testGen

Comment: Thank you. I have found out my mistake and fix it.